# Runtime error using split function to convert string into string array in java

Tags: java

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
        at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
        at Solution.main(Solution.java:94)
```

This code is a solution for one of the problem ons Hackerrank. On Hackerrank, they are using `scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");` to remove this exception. But I want to know what is wrong in my code and how I can remove the exception without using skip function.

```
    import java.util.*;
    class Solution
    {
        public static void minimumBribes(int q[])
        {
            int ans=0;
            for(int i=q.length-1;i>=0;i--)
            {
                if(q[i]-(i+1)>2)
                {
                    System.out.println("Too chaotic");
                    return;
                }
                for(int j=Math.max(0,q[i]-2);j<i;j++)
                {
                    if(q[j]>q[i])
                    {
                        ans++;
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println(ans);
        }
        public static void main(String[]args)
        {
            Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
           Scanner sc1=new Scanner(System.in);
            int t=sc.nextInt();
            for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
            {
                int n=sc.nextInt();
                int q[]=new int[n];
                String[]str=sc1.nextLine().split(" ");

                for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
                {
                    q[j]=Integer.parseInt(str[j]);

                }
                minimumBribes(q);
            }
        }
    }
```

In the above code because of using NextLine, I am getting error, but I want my input to be in this format. Please help to remove this exception.

Answer (score 0):

If the regex phrase "(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?" is the posted solution and you don't wanna skip it, why not try a

```
string.replaceAll("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?", "")
```

on your nextLine() before you split it.

Comment: You mean `replaceAll()`.

Comment: what is( "(\r\n|[\n\r\u2018\u2029\u0085])") doing in our code.

Comment: \r is carriage return, \n is newline, [] means optional, \u2028 stands for unicode character line sperator, \u2029 stands for unicode character paragraph seperator, and \u0085 stands for unicode character next line. What this means is that the replaceAll is removing these characters, aka the whitespaces